# Enum Type Constraint returns error "The signature and implementation are not compatible..."

Tags: f#

I've been trying to follow the guide from [MSDN - Constraints (F#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints) on creating a type within a module which has a generic type constraint of an enum, as follows:

```
type Mapper<'TEnum when 'TEnum : enum<uint32>>() = 
    let dict = new Dictionary<'TEnum, string>()

    member this.Add (key: 'TEnum) (value: string) = 
        dict.Add(key, value)
```

However, I'm getting the error:

> The signature and implementation are not compatible because the
>   declaration of the type parameter 'TEnum' requires a constraint of the
>   form 'TEnum : equality

Is there a way to fix this code example so that I'm able to constrain a type to an enum?

Comment: You'll have to show more of your code. This error means that you're comparing (with operator `=`) values of type `'TEnum` somewhere, but you're not showing that place.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes from the instantiation of `Dictionary<,>`. F# has a special case for this type: it adds an `equality` constraint to its `TKey` generic parameter¹, because, well, dictionary keys have to be comparable, otherwise the dictionary can't function.

You can fix this by adding the constraint to your `'TEnum` parameter:

```
  type Mapper<'TEnum when 'TEnum: enum<uint32> and 'TEnum : equality>() =
```

---

¹<sub>even though the original type definition doesn't have this constraint, because the type is defined in C#</sub>